# How are files and folders moved on most filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, sync, file-management

Some file synchronization programs can detect when a file is moved (as opposed to a file being deleted and another being created). How does this affect synchronization performance? Do they unlink the file from one place and relink it to another instead of deleting and recreating them?